# Can I create a separate stylesheet for IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I created my website using a mac. As you know I can't test it out using Internet Explorer, I left it for the last but expecting layout disasters. The website looks perfect in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. As expected, IE shows it differently. How should I move on from here?

1. Create a style sheet just for IE?
2. Update my existing style sheet to display the website as expected in all the browsers I mentioned earlier?

To me, (1) seems to be the easiest choice so that I can tailor my CSS to display properly in IE without worrying about Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Do you think this is ok?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, You're not asking HOW to make a separate style sheet, correct?

Comment: *If possible*, use a single stylesheet that works in all browsers. That's not always easy but possible. For anything that simply requires IE specific tweaks, use an IE-only stylesheet. **Use a virtual machine to preview IE on OS X.**

Comment: Hi iight, No im not. Im asking if it's alright for me to create a seperate stylesheet.

Comment: Hi Deceze, are you referring to vmware like Parallels?

Comment: I'm referring to products like VMware, Parallels or the free VirtualBox. In fact, you can get a completely free IE testing environment using VirtualBox and virtual machine images provided by Microsoft specifically for IE testing. See https://github.com/xdissent/ievms.

Answer (score 3):

You can target specifically your `stylesheet` for IE only. You will need to put condition code on heading section of the page. See below for examples.

For all IE

```
<!--[if IE]>
For all IE
<![endif]-->
```

If you just want to target to specific version of IE then

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
For only IE 7
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: just bare in mind, that you can't use this methode to adress IE10 and higher seperately

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple things you can do.

- [Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Example of a conditional comment to target all versions of **IE**

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

You can find more conditional comments http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

- [Validate Your Css](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) fixing some obvious markdown mistakes may improve your code immensely.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IE are you targeting? Most of the major pains with IE CSS2 bugs are in IE6, and to a lesser extent, IE7 - however IE8 and IE9 are much better and I haven't experienced any bugs that would require them to have separate stylesheets.

If you are targeting IE6/7 then you have my sympathy, but I don't see why you should bother as IE6 usage is negligible nowadays. However, if you must, then conditional comments are the least painful way of managing the problem. Simply do this in your <head> element:

<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie6patch.css" />
<![endif]-->

Read more here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Also, don't forget to add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> to your page force IE8 and IE9 to use Standards mode.

Answer (score 1):

In the future you can use a css reset to minimize differences between browsers. I have used this one in the past: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Also consider using a template like http://www.99lime.com or similar.

Comment: Hi, 99lime.com undoubtedly offers a great tool to simplify things for me! I have a question. Can i selectively choose certain elements to incorporate into my website? For e,g. i like the slide show element, can i use it in my website? Thanks.

Comment: The slideshow in 99lime is not meant to be customized, so I highly recommend using a popular jquery slider that has good documentation. I like this one: http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider

Answer (score 0):

Check out [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: Thank You everyone! I found out so much today with all your advise.